# How to change a VS Code task's status ? (VS Code extension development)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks, vscode-problem-matcher

I am developing a VS Code extension and there is a customized task in my extension. Everything works well before an update in VS Code recently. The task now seems has a status like below screenshot:

[image]

In the terminal / task window, it shows "Task has errors" and also the task colors red. But actually my task executed correctly. I remember this 'status' doesn't exist before. Do anyone know how to clear this status or how to modify it? I didn't find related APIs or commands in VS Code official document. Could you help give some guidance?

And this is my task settings ('targets' is a customized property):

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "basiccompile",
            "targets": ["TEST_FILE"],
            "label": "basiccompile",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution. According to the latest sample of task-provider, when emit the a close event, you can pass 0 to fire(), then the status would be success.

```
class CustomBuildTaskTerminal implements vscode.Pseudoterminal {
    // ...

    private closeEmitter = new vscode.EventEmitter<number>();
    onDidClose?: vscode.Event<number> = this.closeEmitter.event;

    // ...
    
    open(initialDimensions: vscode.TerminalDimensions | undefined): void {
        // ...
        
        this.closeEmitter.fire(0);
    }
```

Here is the official sample from VS code:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/b7d400880ac08100bd168a22b70d217e6abfd6b9/task-provider-sample/src/customTaskProvider.ts#L129

Answer (score 0):

Quote from the [v1.57 release note](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_57#_task-status-on-terminal-tab):

> #### Task status on terminal tab
>
> The status of a task is now shown in its terminal tab. For background tasks, the status is only shown when there is an associated problem matcher.
>
> [image]

To adjust the associated problem matcher, please see [Modifying an existing problem matcher](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_modifying-an-existing-problem-matcher).

Comment: Thanks for your comments! But seems that doesn't resolve my problem. The "close" property only closes the terminal directly which is not my expectation. I also tried some problem matcher samples mentioned in VS Code documentation, but still not work. The "error" status still there. As I know, problem matchers is empty by default, should not the task display no-error in this case? Thanks!

Comment: @ClaudeZhao Unfortunately, I don't know the answer either, I've updated the question tags, so it can get more attractions.